# What is the benefit of having health check address on different port instead of using a different path?

Tags: architecture, microservices, health-monitoring

When i search best practices for microservice architectures, sometimes a different port from application is used for health check address. Is this a good practice for microservices and what is pros and cons for this method?

Comment: Often security concerns are sited because they might expose information about system internals and state.  It's easy to block a port when your heath checks and/or metrics are done internally, otherwise you'll need to implement the same security you'd do with all other external facing endpoints.  I would think the other reason is for aesthetics... where the port groups like-kind of endpoints - one default port for business, another for stuff not related to regular usage by clients (like metrics, health checks, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, security and implementation cost are good benefits to use this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inherent benefit of making health checks on different port over different URL path - or vice versa.

At the end, the port is just an abstraction of the underlying Operating System, routing traffic to different processes.

What can matter is the concrete network infrastructure / setup in use: Firewall, load balancers, service discovery, etc.

Maybe different ports are easier to configure as rules in the Firewall / IPS / Web Application Firewall? - but this is very implementation specific.

To recap: both are fine. Use what makes your life easier, unless you discover some concrete need by your infrastructure / network setup.

Answer (score 4):

It will benefit if you using a different port and an isolated connection pool for health check API.
Under heavy request => the connection pool of application is full => heal check API can't get process => k8s can't health check application => determine that application is unavailable => k8s kill application => that may give you a more downgrade performance.